# Play functionality in nested loops Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build play functionality using JavaScript to play different colors for my attribute values on map. The basic logic, I am building using simple for loop does not work for me as the loop is played so fast and I only get display last value on Map.

Example:

```
//Hash of my Values
var myHash = {};

myHash['1'] = [10,100];
myHash['2'] = [20,200, 30];
myHash['3'] = [40,300, 4, 5];

function startPlaying() {
    for (item in myHash) {
         var myValues= myHash[item];
         var timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
                         animate(myValues,item);
                         },1000);
    }
} 

function animate(myValues,item) {
    for(i in myValues) {
         //calling my function for each value to play on map with different styles.
         playMyMap();
    }
}
```

I was expecting here that my function startPlaying will fire timeout function three times(for number of items with 1 sec delay) with corresponding myValues and item and It will keep on iterating over myValues individually for three items.

But this doesn't work for me beacuse the myValues gets messed up while each call of setTime out function.

Could anyone please give me an idea here, how can I build such functionality?

Comment: This is a closure issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
                     animate(myValues,item);
                     },1000);
}
```

Will trigger 3 times, but all after 1 second. If you keep a counter you have to do the `1000*counter` to have 1 animate function each second.

The below example uses the `item` as the multiplyer because you start your index with 1. Normally array's start at index 0. If you change your first item to index 0, just do `1000 * (item + 1)` to start with 1 second.

Try this:

```
function startPlaying() {
    for (item in myHash) {
         var myValues= myHash[item];
         var timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
                         animate(myValues,item);
                         },1000 * item );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. you are correct. But do you think there will be any way I can trigger all items together and start playing their values individually. (I mean: item 1,2 and 3 are sent together for three individual loops and each item has again their individual loops to play all the values for that particular item). I know this cannot be done with simple for loops as , the execution will be fast and i am only getting the last values of each item on map while playing). If i try to put a sleep in for loop , then obviously the browser will hang). Any suggestion or idea will be really appreciated.